# Mnemonic to learn all preposition that require accusative case?

Tags: mnemonic

Is there anything like this?
It probably should be in a form of a child story or something similar.

there is one for Dativ:

> "Mit, nach, von, seit, aus, zu, bei verlangen stets Fall Nummer drei."

Comment: which is in Russian?

Comment: Please add a list of all prepositions you want to have covered.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann what do you mean? I need a mnemonic memorize the list)

Comment: @kharandziuk   Funny, yes. But I need the list in order to create a mnomonic sentence for you.

Answer (score 3):

***fub-dog*** suffices (since the somehere else listed *wider* is old-fashioned and *entlang* is not accustive-preposition).

It helps to remember the list: *für, um, bis, durch   ohne, gegen*. Or so I hope.

Comment: @IQV Mh. right. I should integrate *bis*. But *entlang* is change preposition.

Comment: @IQV Da hast du recht, und ist somit das Wort Fudgebow nicht mehr so schön. Denn: Man geht aber *entlang des Weges*. Die Definition einer Akk.-Präposition ist, dass sie ausschliesslich vom Akk. geregelt ist.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this dative-verse is really cute! Although it withholds *binnen, entgegen, gegenüber, gemäß, laut, (mit-)samt* and *zuliebe*. But okay.

I wouldn't know one for the prepositions that can only take the accusative, but as these are: *à, bis, durch, für, gegen, je, per, pro, um* and *wider*, you might want to try

a-bi-du  /  fü-ge-je  /  p-p-um  /  wi und Schluss

I certainly will not ge given the Nobel Price for Literature for that one, but if it helps YOU, it's good enough.

If saying it doesn't help you to remember, sing it. Yes, I'm serious! Maybe there's an old children's song or a folksong or a pop song with a suitable melody. Or try it with your most expressive baritone voice - whatsoever. It works.

Cheers!